# Problem in finding duplicates in a string using bitwise operator

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, bit-manipulation

I think, I have implemented right logic in C++ to find duplicates in a string using bit manipulation. but I am unable to understand why it's not printing anything in terminal. can anyone explain why this problem is occurring here ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
char A[] = "finiding\0";
long int H=0;
long int x=0;
for(int i=0; A[i]!='\0'; i++){
    x=1;
    int temp = A[i];
    x = x<<(temp-97);
    if(x&H > 0){
        printf(" %c duplicate found !",A[i]);
    }else{
        H = x|H;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I have checked the for loop is executing 8 times which is desired according to the string "finding" but control is not going into the if else block which is written into the for loop.

I have used "H" as hashing variable where I am setting the bit which is corresponding to the ASCII code of the character coming into the loop each time. and then using if else I am checking whether the bit is set or not by the concept of masking but still it's not working, and I am unable to understand why it is so.

Comment: You asked yesterday the same question and got answers. You have accepted one. Don't repeat the question.

Comment: What's the significance of `97`?  Do you mean `'a'`?  Prefer to use literal constants for letters rather than their encoding value.  Most people don't have the ASCII chart memorized in decimal.  A lot easier to read a `'a'` than to find an ASCII chart and look up the decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `x&H > 0` is interpreted as `x & (H > 0)` because `>`
operator has higher precedence than `&` operator.

[C++ Operator Precedence - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Add parenthesis to compare the result of AND operation with zero like `(x&H) > 0`.

Comment: Also suggest to enable compiler warnings which would have pointed out this kind of problem for the OP.